# Updating ASP Database from offline HTML5 WebDB (WebSQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-sql

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 application (C#) which contains a database on the server.
I am currently adding offline capability using HTML 5 appcache and WebDB (WebSQL).
All seems to work swimmingly; I can detect connectivity and I can store database entries locally when off-line.

However I have hit a bit of a brick wall attempting to add the offline data to the database on the server.

I am a bit lost as to the concept of both how and where the updates are made. Can updates to the webDB be performed in C# within an aspx page? Or do I need to learn some new technology such as JQuery or JSON?

...I will also need to send updates from the server to the local WebSQL (2 way sync), but am taking one step at a time.